# Solution to Ampersand (&) issue in crosstalk and flexdashboard?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard, ampersand, crosstalk

Ampersand (and sign) (&) turning to "&[amp;]" (I've added in square brackets so you can see it on stack overflow).

I'm using crosstalk filters in a flexdashboard.

One of the options in my crosstalk filter has an ampersand (&) in the name.

When I knit the flexdashboard, the "&" comes out as "&[amp;]" in the crosstalk filter. Therefore the data in the graph and table does not link up. Does anyone know how to make it come out just as "&"?

Example:

"A&Eel pool" turns to "A&[amp;]Eel pool"

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: thanks, I will try creating one